# the right way to limit text? PHP

Tags: php

There is a way to count blank space with `substr`?

```
$testo = $news['testo'];

$testo = strip_tags($testo);

echo "<p>".substr($testo,0,200)."</p>";
```

I did several tests and i see that `substr` does NOT count whitespace. How can I tell him to count them?

This is a problem because it gives me a different number of characters each time for article.

Comment: substr will return a part of a string, not counting ....

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Do you want to limit text using `substr` but you are not getting the expected results and thinks the problem is with the blank spaces? Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any regex to do this (as shown in Ruchish's answer)
Just use [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

```
$fooString = "Hello world string!";
$count = substr_count($fooString, " ");
echo $count; // --> 2
```

### Edit

Of course if you wish to count blank spaces **into a substring**, you can always do something like

```
substr_count(substr($fooString,$start,$length), " ");
```

Where

`$start`    is the starting position of the subset
`$length` is the length of your substr

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$testo = $news['testo'];
$testo = strip_tags($testo);
$count_var = preg_replace('[^\s]', '', $testo);
$count = strlen($count_var);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strlen($testo)>=200)
{
//limit text
    $testo =substr($testo,0,200);

//get last space character
    $space=strrpos($testo, ' ');

// finished
    $testo =substr($testo ,0,$space)." ...";

}

echo $testo;
```